HAL_UART_Transmit_DMA does not send data to serial port
I'm writing an MIDI application on STM32 (NUCLEO-F091RC). I basically have an implementation of midimerger: a program which receives from three different MIDI instruments and merge them into one output (main feature is a channel assignment based on the MIDI input port irrespective of actual channel send by an instrument).
The problem is that sometimes when I press simultaneously two or three keys on a single instruments, messages NoteOn are passing to TX, but after releasing them simultaneously sometimes only two messages NoteOff appear on the output resulting in a one key remaining pressed.
Here are implementation details: I have three UART asynchronous enabled. Two of them are used for RX only, one of them for RX and TX. In a nutshell in the main.cpp I have buffers rx_data for all rx ports and ring buffers for each of them (2*if_n is for historical/experimental reasons with double buffering).
constexpr unsigned int if_n = 3;
uint8_t rx_data[2*if_n];

RingBuffer rb1;
RingBuffer rb2;
RingBuffer rb3;

int main()
{
  ...
  HAL_UART_Receive_DMA(&huart1, &rx_data[0], 1);
  HAL_UART_Receive_DMA(&huart4, &rx_data[2], 1);
  HAL_UART_Receive_DMA(&huart6, &rx_data[4], 1);
  ...

  while (1)
  {
      if (!rb1.is_empty())
          midi1.read_byte(rb1.get());
      if (!rb2.is_empty())
          midi2.read_byte(rb2.get());
      if (!rb3.is_empty())
          midi3.read_byte(rb3.get());
  }
}
...

void HAL_UART_RxCpltCallback(UART_HandleTypeDef *huart)
{
    if (huart->Instance == USART1)
        rb1.put(rx_data[0]);
    else if (huart->Instance == USART4)
        rb2.put(rx_data[2]);
    else if (huart->Instance == USART6)
        rb3.put(rx_data[4]);
}

When data comes to a UART it stores in in a ring buffer. Data from ring buffers are read in a main loop.
When the complete MIDI message is received on a given input interface, the function  MidiOutputInterface::send_message from the following class is being executed:
#include "midi_output_interface.h"
#include "stm32f0xx_hal.h"

static Byte tx_buffer[512];
static int buffer_head = 0;

static Byte channel_mapping[5] = {10, 2, 1, 4, 4};

StatusByte create_status(MidiType inType, Channel inChannel)
{
    return ((Byte) inType | ((inChannel - 1) & 0x0f));
}

void MidiOutputInterface::send(int size)
{
    HAL_UART_Transmit_DMA(_huart, tx_buffer + buffer_head, size);
    buffer_head += size;
    if (buffer_head >= 256)
        buffer_head = 0;
}

void MidiOutputInterface::send_size_one(Message& msg)
{
    if (disableRTmessages)
        return;
    tx_buffer[buffer_head] = msg.type;
    send(1);
}

void MidiOutputInterface::send_size_two(Message& msg, Channel ch)
{
    tx_buffer[buffer_head] = create_status(msg.type, ch);
    tx_buffer[buffer_head + 1] = msg.data1 & 0x7f;
    send(2);
}

void MidiOutputInterface::send_size_three(Message& msg, Channel ch)
{
    tx_buffer[buffer_head] = create_status(msg.type, ch);
    tx_buffer[buffer_head + 1] = msg.data1 & 0x7f;
    tx_buffer[buffer_head + 2] = msg.data2 & 0x7f;
    send(3);
}

Channel MidiOutputInterface::channel(Message& msg, int id) const
{
    return passThrough ? msg.channel : channel_mapping[id];
}

void MidiOutputInterface::send_sysex(Message& msg, int id)
{
    const auto size = msg.getSysExSize();
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    {
        tx_buffer[buffer_head + i] = msg.sysexArray[i];
    }
    send(size);
}

void MidiOutputInterface::send_message(Message msg, int id)
{
    if(msg.type == MidiType::SystemExclusive)
    {
        send_sysex(msg, id);
        return;
    }

    const Channel ch = channel(msg, id);
    const auto size = msg.size;

    switch (size)
    {
    case 1:
        send_size_one(msg);
        break;
    case 2:
        send_size_two(msg, ch);
        break;
    case 3:
        send_size_three(msg, ch);
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
}


The important thing is the MIDI message is inserted into tx_buffer (method send_size_three since the problem mainly concerns this case) and then it calls HAL_UART_Transmit_DMA with a proper parameters.
The question is, why sometimes some messages are lost in transmission? When in debug mode I looked at the tx_buffer everything seems ok, although in this case one of NoteOff messages was not transmitted to output:
enter image description here
On positions 36, 39, 42 we see a message NoteOn (\220) on keys C (60), D (62), E (64). Next are three NoteOff messages (\200 on 45, 48, 51). So everything was received. But this screen from debugger was mede when one of the three keys remains depressed, i.e. NoteOff message was not transmitted. Any ideas why this happens?
The MIDI functionality you see here is based on this library: https://github.com/SpMakris/STM32_UART_MIDI
I started with it, but it does not have interrupts, DMA and buffers, so I heavily modified it but left some of the implementation (parsing midi messages etc.).
I experimented with double buffering on inputs, circular buffers, different UART ports. The last thing I noticed is the presence of all messages in tx_buffer (described above) and that's where I have no idea how to proceed.
EDIT:
By @pmacfarlane suggestion I modified the sending part. Now data are just added to a tx_buffer and actual sending is done from main loop with blocking (max_buffer_head is just for debugging purposes):
void MidiOutputInterface::send(int size)
{
    buffer_head += size;
    to_send += size;
    max_buffer_head = buffer_head > max_buffer_head
            ? buffer_head
            : max_buffer_head;
}

void MidiOutputInterface::uart_transmit()
{
    if(is_ready && to_send > 0)
    {
        is_ready = false;
        HAL_UART_Transmit_IT(_huart, tx_buffer, to_send);
        to_send = 0;
        buffer_head = 0;
    }
}

void MidiOutputInterface::reset_state()
{
    is_ready = true;
}


An here's the main loop and callback:
int main(void)
{
...
while (1)
  {
      if (!rb1.is_empty()) midi1.read_byte(rb1.get());
      if (!rb2.is_empty()) midi2.read_byte(rb2.get());
      if (!rb3.is_empty()) midi3.read_byte(rb3.get());
      midi_out.uart_transmit();
    /* USER CODE END WHILE */

    /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */
  }
...
}

...

void HAL_UART_TxCpltCallback(UART_HandleTypeDef* huart)
{
    if(huart->Instance == USART6)
        midi_out.reset_state();
}

This improves a lot. Now the whole thing works almost perfectly although from time to time it still sometimes loses a message although this time it happens rarely: I can plan a whole piece and it happens once or less.

You should check the return values from all your HAL function calls. My guess would be that you are calling HAL_UART_Transmit_DMA() while a previous DMA is still ongoing. If you checked the return value you would see that, if that is indeed the case.

@pmacfarlane: indeed: I change a bit the sending part. Now I just add data to a tx_buffer and an actual call to HAL is made in main loop and, what's important it's blocking against another call until callback. More in edited version.
